# Android crashes when record HD video Galaxy SII

Tags: android, camera, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

when trying to set MediaRecorder with following settings fps > 15, resolution 1080p,

on method `recorder.prepare()` device hangs, and then Android crashes.

Can Galaxy SII record video with 1080p resolution?
Thanks.

Comment: @Yahor10 Hi, there's no stacktrace actually. After recorder.prepare() my app hangs and the device just turns off.

Comment: It should be in all messages(no filter) logcat tag

Comment: @Yahor10 Yes, should be. But after recorder.prepare() device turns off without any logs, even system logs.

Comment: Surroud with try catch your recorder.prepare(). I suppose the problem is in your video file

Comment: @Yahor10 Actually this method is in try block. And this issue happens only on Galaxy SII device.

Answer (score -1):

here is the reason for unable to play hd videos on mobile 
http://cyber-progo.blogspot.in/2013/04/why-we-cannot-record-hd-videos-on-any.html